# $B^{1/2}$ dense in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I try to understand the following proof , that cameron martin space $B^{1/2}$ is dense in Hilbert space H.

Suppose that $kerB=\left \{ 0 \right \}$ and take $x\in H$ such that $\langle B^{1/2}a,x\rangle=0$ for all $a\in H$.By symmetry of B we will have $\langle a,B^{1/2}x\rangle =0$   , hence $B^{1/2}x=0$ and $Bx=0$ which implies that $x=0$. So $B^{1/2}(H)$ is dense in hilbert space H.

I can't really connect this proof with the dense definition that I know:

That a subspace A of H is dense in H if the closure of A is equal to H.

Any advise will be really helpful.